# IIS Server, sudden 404.4 on all sites The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, httphandler

I have a long standing IIS 7.5 box that suddenly stopped working mid morning today. Something has obviously changed but I have been unable to determine what and would appreciate any suggestion.

All of the sites on the IIS server have started returning the same error page when viewed locally -
HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.

The server has a number of web sites on it, mostly asp.net but there are some others.

Things I have tried (in no particular order) -

- Restarting the IIS Server
- Restarting the Windows Server
- Setting up a plain static html website
- Comparing applicationhost.config with the versions in the history folder
- Checking the handlers appear to be configured correctly (they do as fas as I can see).
- Added FX_schema.patch.xml as per
  [Unrecognized element 'ProviderOption' when trying to use Powershell Set-WebConfigurationProperty](https://serverfault.com/questions/629254/unrecognized-element-provideroption-when-trying-to-use-powershell-set-webconfi)
- Checked the server logs but can't see anything around the time this started.

I'm at a loss now for ideas so would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the source of this. A global rewrite rule had been setup that was redirecting everything.Disabling this meant all the sites were working again.

All I need to do now is figure out who made the change and have a quiet word with them!

Comment: It is always hard to track down such changes, https://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/iis-7-5-how-to-enable-iis-configuration-auditing So a better idea is to log who logged on to that server and confront that guy.

Comment: If only I'd know about that before, thanks for the link